# E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.example.talls.networkstest': Connection refused

Tags: android, sockets

I have recently started out in Android and started to use sockets. But, the moment I run my program, 
**E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.example.talls.networkstest': Connection refused**
This message appears.

Below is my code:

```
package com.example.talls.tcpserver;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Thread thread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        thread.start();
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        public void run(){
            TextView text = findViewById(R.id.serverip);
            try {
                ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8080);
                text.setText(ss.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
                ss.accept();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Below is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.talls.tcpserver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Additional log:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cNiiWThHi5k4ttQkmABA0H3O1HP5eIwk

Phone used:
Google Pixel XL2
Samsung S9

Both phones gave the same error message;
E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'localabstract:com.example.talls.networkstest': Connection refused

Comment: Have you added the `android.permission.INTERNET` to your manifest?

Comment: Yes,  these are the list of permission I have added:<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Were you able to solve?

Comment: Hi Sumukha, I wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem in the end. Turns out, I have accidentally keyed in some proxy settings via the settings terminal. It got fixed by removing those settings.